# How to put 10secs duration and 1min interval in Arduino w/ Solenoid valve & soil moisture sensor?

Tags: arduino, sensors

so i have this project which is an automated water sprinkler and i am using a solenoid valve in controlling the water, controlled by arduino and a soil moisture sensor. the code is working at first until i put the while condition on the else clause and added the delays. I have to put 10 seconds duration in the water sprinkling, and 1 minute interval before the water flows again until the sensor reaches the required moisture. Pleeeease take a look.

```
const int soil_moisture_sensor = A0;
int ledPin_Red = 13;
int ledPin_Green = 12;


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin_Red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin_Green, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
int soil_moisture_level = analogRead(soil_moisture_sensor);
  if (soil_moisture_level <=560 && soil_moisture_level <=700 ) {
           digitalWrite(ledPin_Red, LOW);//when the water is enough 
               digitalWrite(ledPin_Green, HIGH);//GREEN LED Lights up
        Serial.println("water is enough!");
            }

    else if (soil_moisture_level <=360 && soil_moisture_level > 360 && soil_moisture_level <= 560) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin_Red, HIGH);// LED RED lights up
                digitalWrite(ledPin_Green, LOW);
                Serial.println("the water is half full!");
                            }
    else {
             while (soil_moisture_level > 700)
              {
                  digitalWrite(ledPin_Red, HIGH);//LED RED on
                  delay(10000);//10 secs on of red led
                  digitalWrite(ledPin_Red, LOW);//LED RED off
                  delay(60000);//60 secs or 1 min interval
                  digitalWrite(ledPin_Green, LOW);
                  Serial.println("no more water");
              }
         }
        delay(2000); //2000 ms = 2 secs
}
```

Your help will be much appreciated! thaaaaanks! :D

Comment: Since the code is working fine, what have you tried to do already? SO is not a code writing service - we like to see the effort you've put in!

Comment: Not a problem - just want to make sure you start off on the right foot with the SO community. You should add your attempt to your post, too, so people can help make it work for you

Comment: oh im sorry. i put a while loop in the else statement for the red LED that contains a code where the red LED would blink, just in case it can set the on and off of the solenoid. everytime i run the program with this code, the delay time for the reading of the sensor is affected and the elseif and if clause were not working anymore. here's the code i added.

Comment: else {
                  while (soil_moisture_level > 700)
                  {
                      digitalWrite(ledPin_Red, HIGH);//LED RED on
                      delay(10000);//10 secs on of red led
                      digitalWrite(ledPin_Red, LOW);//LED RED off
                      delay(60000);//60 secs or 1 min interval
                      digitalWrite(ledPin_Green, LOW);
                      Serial.println("no more water");
                  }
      }

Comment: i edited the codes on my post. my bad. :)

Comment: if moisture level is less than or equal to 560 AND less than or equal to 700?  you have a lot of redundancy here.  if level is less than or equal to 360 and greater than 360 and less than or equal to 560 ???? how is that condition ever met?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your comparator backwards. Should be soil_moisture_level < 700